# pandas group by time unit specified by frequency string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Suppose I have a dataframe with timestamps and counts:

```
df=pandas.DataFrame(data={
    'date':pandas.to_datetime([
       '2014-08-18 12:01:00',
       '2014-08-18 13:01:00',
       '2014-08-19 12:07:00']),
    'count':[1, 1, 3]})
```

There are measurements on different days at corresponding hours (`12`) or minutes(`01`). No specific periodicity is guaranteed, just timestamps.

I can group measurements by minute or by hour using `dt` accessor:

```
 df.groupby(df.date.dt.minute).mean()
>>>      count
date
1         1
7         3
```

or:

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.hour).mean()
      count
date
12        2
13        1
```

**Question:**
Can I do the same grouping using [frequency strings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) rather than explicitly typing fields of the accessor? (e.g. `"W"`,`"D"`,`"min"` as in `freq` argurment to `pandas.Grouper`)

Comment: you can use “dt.floor(‘d’)”

Comment: Look into [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html), which allows you to specify a `freq` argument, and works for more general things like `W` which are problematic with `.floor`

Comment: @ALollz, yes I know it allows `freq`, that's why I've mentioned it in the last sentence of the question. However with `min` argument, it will group two minutes or two hours from different days into two different groups, whereas the desired behavior is to combine them into one. (I've corrected typo in the first example of desired output)

Comment: Then no, you cannot use the `frequency strings` because you aren't grouping by any meaningful frequency. `.floor` is the closest you'll get to using them, but it wont work for everything because things like `'M'` aren't a fixed frequency.